# SQL SERVER Query to pick up the the Max(Balance) and its ShareAccountHolderCount for the account number from the all the account types

Tags: sql-server

Am trying to resolve the below query. Please could you help?

**BANKTABLE BT**

```
AccountNumber   AccountTypeCode     Balance         ShareAccountHolderCount
10800           2146                    160                 5
10800           2148                    126                 3
10800           2149                    84                  6
10800           2147                    66                  7
11039           2581                    42                  1
11039           2582                    32                  21
11039           2579                    10                  91
11039           2578                    7                   10
```

**Requirement:**
1. A Account Number(BT.AccountNumber) might have accounts in multiple AccountTypes(BT.AccountTypeCode) and
for the each account type he might have the different balances(BT.Balance).
2. Under the account for multiple accounttypes, he might have number of Shared account holders(BT.ShareAccountHolderCount)
3. I don't have another table to join with the BANKTABLE

**Question:** Now I have to pick up the the Max(Balance) and its ShareAccountHolderCount for the account number from the all the account types

The **Result** Should look like as below.

```
AccountNumber   AccountTypeCode     Balance         ShareAccountHolderCount
10800           2146                    160                 5
11039           2581                    42                  1
```

As per my research
**Answer 1:** TOP 1 and Order by Balance DESC Won't work for this requirement.
**Answer 2:** Am trying to do something by writing below query, But not able to achieve the answer

```
SELECT AccountNumber,AccountTypeCode,Balance,ShareAccountHolderCount
        ,RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AccountNumber ORDER BY  LongestStressdays DESC)
        ,RowNumber2 = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY AccountNumber ORDER BY  CountOfTestTypeIdsperSequence DESC)
        FROM BANKTABLE BT
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are near of solution. Second part consist in filter rows to get only the first row by partition:

```
with cte as (
   SELECT 
       AccountNumber,
       AccountTypeCode,
       Balance,
       ShareAccountHolderCount,
       RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
               PARTITION BY AccountNumber 
               ORDER BY  Balance DESC)
   FROM BANKTABLEL BT
)
   select
     AccountNumber,
     AccountTypeCode,
     Balance,
     ShareAccountHolderCount
   from
     cte
   where RowNumber = 1
```

Comment: ,Thats Way I'll be in touch with StackOverflow, Yes Your right. I got the results.Thank You Very Much